# Can you import a Postgresql 9.5.10 db into a Postgresql 10.9 server?

Tags: database-migration, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-10

I would like to know if it is safe to import a dump made from a database running on a PostgreSQL server 9.5.10 to a PostgreSQL server 10.9.

Basically I am able to do the import. It does not fail. But how can I be sure nothing in the schema has been lost somehow ? We are talking Production here.

Comment: This question is better suited for [dba.se]. This site is for programming (code) and programmers tools related questions.

Comment: Yes, that's absolutely safe. It's even one of the [recommended ways](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/upgrading.html) to do an upgrade.